# Delete Matched Id in Nested Array in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have a delete button that have I set some static datas. In it I passed some ids. Matched ids should be deleted when you click the button.
My problem is that I can't delete any item that matched its id.

Codesandbox is here [CLICK HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/delete-array-qgjxf?file=/src/reducers/productReducer.js)

```
case appConstants.DELETE_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state.products.map((product) => ({
      ...product,
      productImages: (product.productImages ?? []).filter(
        ({ id }) => !id.includes(action.payload)
      )
    }))
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in filtering function - you're confused `String.prototype.includes` and `Array.prototype.includes`.

Right way to do this is to check for `productImage.id` in `action.payload`, not vice versa:

```
case appConstants.DELETE_IMAGE_SUCCESS:
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state.products.map((product) => ({
      ...product,
      productImages: (product.productImages ?? []).filter(
        ({ id }) => !action.payload.includes(id)
      )
    }))
  };
```

[`String.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) and [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) work in the similar way, but have different APIs - first accepts `string` as argument, second - `Array`.